# Converting Go testing output to XUnit

Tags: jenkins, go, xunit

How can I have the output of Go's testing library output in XUnit format for integration with Jenkins? There are no command line options to output to XML or to XUnit format with `go test`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a nice little plugin to convert: https://github.com/tebeka/go2xunit

To install it:

```
go get github.com/tebeka/go2xunit
```

To use it:

```
# Run your tests like normal, but pipe the verbose output to the converter
go test -v | $GOPATH/bin/go2xunit > test_output.xml
```

If you have `$GOPATH/bin` in your normal `$PATH`:

```
go test -v | go2xunit > test_output.xml
```

Comment: `github.com/tebeka/go2xunit` is archived repo now. Any updated one?

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram https://github.com/jstemmer/go-junit-report