# Is it possible to print golang unit test results out to a file?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I run `go test` in my pkg directory and I get the test results printed to the console as they run, but it would be ideal if I could get them printed to a txt file or even a html file, is it possible to do this? I know you can get coverage reports out from it and generate html files for those which is excellent, but I would have thought it possible to do the same just for the actual results of the tests i.e which tests ran, which passed and which failed. I've been searching the net but even `go test help` doesn't offer any suggestions for printing results out to a file.

Comment: Does `go test > test.out` work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Go testing output to XUnit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958647/converting-go-testing-output-to-xunit)

Comment: go test > test.out was exactly what I wanted thankyou very much @JakeBurkhead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2018: [Go 1.10+](https://go.dev/doc/devel/release#go1.10)

As noted in [Yoshiki Shibukawa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709902/yoshiki-shibukawa)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77194558/6309), you have [`cmd/test2json`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/test2json)

```
go tool test2json [-p pkg] [-t] [./pkg.test -test.v=test2json]
```

Other approaches around `go tool test2json`:

- [`KacperPerschke/json2test`](https://github.com/KacperPerschke/json2test): Reverts the result of go tool `test2json`.
- [`TaylorOno/golandreporter`](https://github.com/TaylorOno/golandreporter) Ginkgo does not output results in a format which can be converted into JSON (via `go tool test2json`, which is used by Goland to get a list of output. This reporter will trick `test2json` into outputting the Ginkgo specs similar to go test output.

---

2015: Since I only want to see failed test, I have this script "`gt`" that I run instead of go test:

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out %*|grep -v -e "^\.\.*$"|grep -v "^$"|grep -v "thus far"
```

That way, it filters everything but the failed cases.
And you can redirect its content to a file, as mentioned: `gt > test.out`

It also generates code coverage, which is why I have another script "`gc`":

```
grep -v -e " 1$" coverage.out
```

That way, I don't even wait for a brower to open, I directly see the list of lines which are not yet covered (ie, which don't end with ' `1`' in the `coverage.out` file)

Comment: is there a way to store the output of go test command ? I am only interested in the end result, may be
just "pass" or "fail"

Comment: @AnoopGoudar You could use the exit status of the go test command: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25989#issuecomment-399275051

Answer (score 4):

This will append test results to the `test.out` file.

```
go test >> test.out
```

This will overwrite the test results for each test run.

```
go test > test.out
```

Answer (score 3):

"go test -json" is available from go 1.10. It calls test2json command inside the process and generates JSON output to console.

- https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/test2json

There are several tools that consume the json and generate HTML or JUnit XML on GitHub.

Comment: Good point. Upvoted. I have included a reference to your answer in mine.